# Store IP or set cookie for PHP POLL?

Tags: php

I would like to make a voting system for my site. I need to check whether a user has voted already. Do I need to store the IP of the user or do I need to store a cookie in the users computer, then make validation if the IP is already used for voting or a cookie is already stored to the user's computer.

Answer (score 0):

Neither of those will give you a flawless script because the user can still clear the cookies or browser a proxy to revote. However I would use both cookies and ip-adress in case the user have a dynamic ip adress or clearing the cookies.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest do both, as an IP can change and a cookie can be deleted.

Also if you want more accuracy, you can use Flash's [LocalSharedObjects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_Shared_Object) also known as FlashCookies to store whether a person has already voted or not. Much less people could/would delete these on regular basis.

Answer (score 0):

i think the best way is have a user registration system to store user information like polling and etc.then  you can easily check that user voted already or no ? this way is more secure than others.but for other option that you can consider,you can [store user's mac adress](http://forums.techarena.in/software-development/1179119.htm).the mac adress is better that ip and cookie.but storing all information help you to have a good vote system.